# Is there a way to copy/initialize values in a set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, update, azure-sql-database

What I want to do ([I know this does not work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ae268bb2-0dbd-4474-99e6-3cd864fb073b/does-merge-or-update-guarantee-set-order-assignment?forum=transactsql)) is:

```
update stats
set BandwidthLastMonth = BandwidthThisMonth, 
    BandwidthThisMonth=0 
where myPk = 3
```

Is there a way to do this in a select statement? Or do I need to write a stored procedure and hit each record twice (I sure hope not).

My solution needs to work for Sql Azure and Sql Server 2008.

Comment: What do you mean *"this does not work"*? Seems like a valid statement to me.

Comment: @ypercube - Sorry, forgot the link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ae268bb2-0dbd-4474-99e6-3cd864fb073b/does-merge-or-update-guarantee-set-order-assignment?forum=transactsql

Comment: I don't see how those MERGE statements are similar to yours. You don't seem to use variables either, so I stand with my first comment. Provide the exact query/statement you use and why it does not work (sample data, before and after the statement would be good.)

Comment: Do you mean updating at table using the results of a `SELECT` statement? e.g. `UPDATE x SET x.x1 = y.x1 FROM x INNER JOIN y ON y.y1 = x.y1 WHERE...`

Comment: @MarkSinkinson no, all of the update is on a single table.

Comment: @ypercube My concern is not does it work, it's is it correct. If it works but there's no guarantee that it will do so in the future (ie the official result is undefined), then I'm one service pack away from my code breaking.

Comment: Well, provide the code! We are still waiting. `UPDATE column_a = column_b, column_b = 0 FROM tablename WHERE (whatever);` works 100% and there is no need to worry for anything. If it's not a table but a view or a complex join, if these are not columns but variables or whatever, then, show us the code.

Comment: @ypercube I put in an explicit where clause but yes, just a table and nothing weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until we see the actual code, we can only speculate but for what is worth, I'll do a guess.

Assuming that your code involves only a table and its columns (no @variables involved) and is something like:

```
UPDATE
    tablename
SET
    column_a = column_b, 
    column_b = 0 
WHERE 
    (condition) ;
```

It is valid SQL and 100% correct. Correct, meaning that after the update `column_a` will have the values that `column_b` had before the update and `column_b` will have `0`, for all rows that pass the `(condition)`.

SQL-Server follows this behaviour strictly and there is no reason to assume that it will deviate from the standard in a future release.

SQL works in sets and the updates are done "simultaneously" on the whole row. (they may not be done simultaneously but the result is the same as if they were.) You could change the code to this and the result will be (guaranteed) the same:

```
...
SET
    column_b = 0,
    column_a = column_b
...
```

In fact, the following is valid and equivalent SQL as well (although not yet implemented in SQL-Server);

```
UPDATE
    tablename
SET
    (column_a, column_b) = (column_b, 0) 
WHERE 
    (condition) ;
```

I haven't tested Azure but if it deviated from this basic SQL behaviour, it would better be documented somewhere.